# Mongoose document save fails with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a few "ref" properties. Recently (I believe after upgrading to a recent version of mongoose), my saves have started failing unless I populate() the ref fields. The error it fails with is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

Has anyone else seen this? I suppose I can work around it by always populating, but I'd like to understand why this is necessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was caused by my custom toObject and toJSON transform, which was removing properties I don't want serialized when returning JSON through my API.

I didn't realize it also affected Mongoose's serialization to MongoDB.

**Edit**: it can also be caused by trying to save a document with 'ref' properties which were not populated!

Comment: +1 to the mention of ref properties; for me it was caused by trying to save a doc that had a ref property that was hydrated (an object), instead of just being the `_id`.

Comment: Good catch on 'ref' properties issue. That's was my problem.

Comment: Same here, my ref property was an empty object.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and it helped to send the HTTP header field `Content-Type: application/json` which was previously missing.
Adding this helped.

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your solution but I solved the issue by making a copy of the JS object before saving to mongo. It seems as Nodejs has added some properties like __ proto __ or something which caused saving to fail. But it could be that the objects are handled differently (no adding of __ proto __ for example) when you put the proper Content-Type. Didn't try it though.